# How to stop or pause this program?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I try to use clearTimeout, but failed, can anyone show me how to stop or pause this animation? Below is my javascript code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
}

function myFunction() {
   var m = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = m;
}

function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {

    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    var m = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
    myRectangle.y = 380 - m * Math.cos(time * Math.PI / 2000);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

   requestAnimFrame(function() {
      animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
    });
}

var myRectangle = {
    x: 150,
    y: 150,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 4
};

drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

setTimeout(function() {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
}, 0);
```

Comment: To "stop" the animation stop calling `requestAnimFrame(...)` in `animate()`

Comment: Is this the full script? Where are you declaring canvas and context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback should stop calling requestAnimationFrame

```
var stop = false;
function stopAnimation() {
    stop = true;
}

function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {

    // ...

    if (stop) {
        stop = false;
    }
    else {
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
            animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. It took me half a day to stop the program, now problem solved! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the easiest is to store the timeout in a variable that you can later clear, such as

```
var myTimeout = 0;
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
            myTimeout = window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

...

function stopAnimation () {
  if (myTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. This is also the first thing I tried, but it didn't work... I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

Try saving the id of your `Timeout` when you set it:

```
var timeoutId = window.setTimeout(...);
```

Then, to stop the animation, it should be as simple as clearing the timeout using the id:

```
function stopAnimation(timeoutId) {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is only used to start the first iteration. And with a timeout of `0` you won't be fast enough to stop it ;) The repetition only occurs because of the `requestAnimFrame(...)` call in `animate()`